# mod rewrite and full url with paramaters as parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want get full url with parameters to index.php, rewrite with mod_rewrite

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

index.php is only

```
print_r($_GET);
```

when i try

```
domain.tld/http://asdf/asdf&s=1%3fb=3&c=34
```

i get

```
Array
(
    [q] => http://asdf/asdf
    [s] => 1?b=3
    [c] => 34
)
```

but i need something like this:

```
Array
(
    [q] => http://asdf/asdf&s=1%3fb=3&c=34 //some complicated url
)
```

Is there any (simple) way ? I found many solutions for different parameters, not for all-in-one.
Sorry for my english  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\S+)
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?q=%1 [B,L]
```

Comment: Just fyi that this problem is **pretty tricky** and both `%{THE_REQUEST}` and flag `B` have very important role to play here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, in your example URI, the query string is not well formed, causing Apache to interpret a portion of the string `(that part starting with`&s=...`) as a query string.

In essence, this means Apache considers this to be the input:

```
URI => http://asdf/asdf
Query String => s=1%3fb=3&c=34
```

The redirect rule only operates on the URI portion, and then via `QSA` flag appends the query string, thus you get something like the following as the rewritten request:

```
index.php?q=http://asdf/asdf&s=1%3fb=3&c=34
```

You will need to first URL-encode the query string. For example that might be something similar to the what is produced by the following:

```
$query_string = urlencode('http://asdf/asdf&s=1?b=3&c=34');
```

and then to prevent Apache from re-encoding (double-encoding) it, use a `NE` flag in the redirect rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,NE,QSA]
```

Comment: i forgot: url is from internet - i dont know what i get. So urlencode its not usefull